# null pointer exception in intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to call an Activity but it shows a null pointer exception on line 17. I have just started learning Android Studio. 
Please help me out with this problem, and also explain where I'm going wrong.

```
public class activity2 extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Button B2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B2);
        B2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent ladoo = new Intent(activity2.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(ladoo);
                finish();
            }
        });
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code of line 17?

Comment: `startActivity(ladoo);`

Comment: Please show the log cat.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at application.trend.seva.intent_base.activity2.onCreate(activity2.java:17)`

Comment: still not working` Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at application.trend.seva.intent_base.activity2.onCreate(activity2.java:17)`

Comment: So you only have that problem when the user clicks the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the problem of the `super.onCreate()` placement, the problem is that you're not calling `SetContentView()`, so there is no active inflated view with which to reference your `Button` object.

```
public class activity2 extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //add this here
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2); //reference whatever the layout.xml file is named for this Activity

        Button B2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B2);
        B2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent ladoo = new Intent(activity2.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(ladoo);
                finish();
            }
        });
        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //remove from here
    }
}
```

See [Documentation Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View))

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing MainActivity.this with just this, so

```
Intent ladoo = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(ladoo);
```

Not sure why this would work, but when I use intent, I always just use "this" as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be that `activity2.class` is not an activity, but rather a class.

Hope this helps, feel free to ask me questions I know how it feels to be a beginner.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment rather than an answer

Comment: @AlexanderZhak which I would have done if I had enough reputation, thank you.